# K3S kubernetes Insecure Registries in daemon.json doesn't work

Tags: docker, kubernetes, k3s

I'm using k3s to deploy my cluster, in my worker node I already setup insecure registries in /etc/docker/daemon.json for an internal network private registry

```
{ "insecure-registries": ["192.168.30.87:7111"] }
```

and I have restarted both my docker and my machine. I can see the settings from `docker info`
[image]

when I ran

```
docker run 192.168.30.87:7111/linhnvh/user-service-image:latest
```

it worked perfectly

But I also set the image within my kubernetes deployment
[image]

when I apply the deployment I'm getting the following error:

[image]

Why is this still not working within my kubernetes cluster? I can run `docker run` normally on the worker node with the image url

[image]

it just doesn't work for kubernetes deployment? The `insecure-registries` settings is there in docker info

As I'm coding on a streaming machine so I can't copy paste images.

Comment: there are no authentication on this local network registry @P....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

finally after 4 hours of searching i finally come into this issue https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/issues/1802

Because i'm using k3s for cluster setup it's using crictl instead of docker, so the daemon.json doesn't apply
which bring me to this documentation https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/installation/private-registry/

i created `registries.yaml` in at /etc/rancher/k3s/ with the following content:

```
mirrors:
  "192.168.30.87:7111":
    endpoint:
      - "http://192.168.30.87:7111"
```

after saving i restart the k3s service with `systemctl restart k3s`

after that my pod able to pull the image, remember to set the ip both and after `endpoint` in registries.yaml

This need to be set on all node that gonna create a pod, and the restart command of service will be different

on master node: `systemctl restart k3s`

on worker/agent node: `systemctl restart k3s-agent`